# Using Android TCP Client app to interface with sensor

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

UPDATE #2: BLUF: I think I found the problem, but I need help figuring out how to fix it.  The device needs a command with prefix and suffix STX>command ETX> (I had to drop the open bracket so stackoverflow would show it).  When I send over TCP using Hercules (which works), the host interprets STX> and ETX> correctly and just displays "command", however I wrote a java client program that sends the same information but it shows up on the host as "STX>commandETX>".  What is java doing differently?

---

Original:

I've been troubleshooting this for the last few days and I'm out of ideas so here I am.  First some background information that may or may not be relevant:
I have a SICK LMS151 LIDAR sensor that I need to access through an Android application.  The sensor is designed as a TCP server so you connect as a client and send the command STX>sRN LMDscandataETX>.  This cues the sensor to spit a bunch of data back to the client.  On a computer I can use a program like Hercules in TCP client mode, send the command and instantly receive the data without issue.  However getting an Android app to do the same has been problematic (I've attached the client code below).
I wrote a server app on a separate android device which my client app has been able to connect to and exchange data.  I send the command "STX>sRN LMDscandataETX>" through the connection and that's exactly how it shows up on the server side.  When the server app sends data, I can see it on my client. However, when I attempt to connect to the sensor with the client, it connects but does not respond to my request for data.  Any ideas of issues to look into would be helpful because at this point I'm fresh out.  Thanks!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class TcpClient extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        runTcpClient();
    }

private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 2111;
private void runTcpClient() {
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.105", TCP_SERVER_PORT);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
Log.i("TcpClient", "Connected!");
        //send output msg
        String outMsg = "<STX>sRN LMDscandata<ETX>"; 
        out.write(outMsg);
        out.flush();
        Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);
        //accept server response
        String inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Log.i("TcpClient", "received: " + inMsg);
        //close connection
        s.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

UPDATE:  Spent some more time on this today.  Added a BoundedInputStream from Apache in hopes that maybe I wasn't seeing anything because the sensor wasn't sending a /n character at the end of each reading.  Also converted from BufferedReader to Scanner.  No luck.  I'm fairly convinced now that it's not a problem with my client reading but instead it is somehow sending the command differently from the computer such that it isn't understood by the sensor.

Comment: I was going to suggest a missing newline on the command side as a suspect, but perhaps you have already checked that.  Can you set up a packet scanner somewhere (perhaps on a router?) that will see all traffic going to/from the sensor?  It looks like that instrument is proxying some older serial protocol over TCP, so it's also possible that its networking implementation is something rather "unsophisticated" that was grafted on to an earlier design as an afterthought (ie, buggy, or picky about details it shouldn't be).  Can you talk to it from something like connectbot on the Android device?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  To be honest, I'm not sure how to set up a packet scanner on a router but I think you're right that the sensor was designed as a serial device originally.  I downloaded Connectbot and it seems to connect but I can't figure out how to type data in the app.  Instead, I downloaded another app called TCP Client.  It connects and I can send the data, but the sensor won't respond to it either.  One observation through testing though that might be useful: The tcp server I wrote responds immediately to my java tcp program, but hangs up until disconnect with Hercules....weird.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this issue and I think its worth sharing.  After using wireshark I found that the command that worked is substituting STX> and ETX> for \u0002 and \u0003.  These are standard TCP headers and footers.  I manually went into my code to make the substitution and voila! It worked.

Comment: "These are standard TCP headers and footers" - no.

Comment: @Malt You made a correction without providing any details so my assumption is that you don't have a source.  \u is the code to indicate a unicode message and STX (eg. \x02) is a standard "start token" delimiter used to send packetized data:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_8.6.0/com.ibm.rational.rit.protocol.doc/topics/t_tcp_udp_sockets_creating_physical_tcp_servers.html
TCP is new to me so please correct me if you have better information.  I'm just asking for more details than "no".

Comment: STX and ETX are symbols sometimes used as delimiters. They have little to do with TCP except the fact that TCP is a stream based protocol, and one of the approaches to reading messages from stream based protocols, is using delimiters. The delimiters can be anything that does not appear in the message. For instance, in HTTP (TCP based) the delimiters are newlines. On the other hand "standard TCP headers" are these things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure which have nothing to do with STX and ETX.